# why does my function not load the filters into a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to get some help with my Udacity project. it's the famous US bikeshare project!
You are supposed to create an interactive program where you ask the user to input one of three cities: chicago, washington, or new york city. one of the first 6 months and a weekday.
a function is supposed to get the three filters, city, month and day. another function is then supposed to load the filters and create a filtered DataFrame. then some statistics take place.

My problem happens whenever i try to filter data by choosing a specific month not all and a specific day not all...it seems that for some reason it returns an empty DataFrame!
i've looked into several codes out there and my load function is straight forward!

```
  def load_data(city, month, day):
"""
Loads data for the specified city and filters by month and day if applicable.

Args:
    (str) city - name of the city to analyze
    (str) month - name of the month to filter by, or "all" to apply no month filter
    (str) day - name of the day of week to filter by, or "all" to apply no day filter
Returns:
    df - Pandas DataFrame containing city data filtered by month and day
"""
#let's first load the data from the csv file!
df = pd.read_csv(CITY_DATA[city])
#now, we convert the start time column to datatime as in practice problem
df['Start Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Start Time'])
#now we get the month and day from Start Time like in the practice problem
df['month'] = df['Start Time'].dt.month
df['day_of_week'] = df['Start Time'].dt.day_name
df['hour'] = df['Start Time'].dt.hour
#now let's get the filters for month and day if the user didn't choose all
if month != 'all':
    #first we get the index of the month then we create a new filtered df
    month = MONTH_DATA.index(month)
    df = df[df['month']==month]

if day != 'all':
    df= df[df['day_of_week'] == day.title()]

return df
```

when i filter for jan and sun for example it gives me this:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Unnamed: 0, Start Time, End Time, Trip Duration, Start Station, End Station, User 
Type, Gender, Birth Year, month, day_of_week, hour]
Index: []
```

any help? :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and the [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and make sure the code appears exactly as you actually have it. What you show would cause syntax errors. Also, read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and explain: why *should* the result be different? Exactly what result do you expect with those filters? Can you show us an exact input that causes the problem, and exact corresponding desired output?

Comment: Finally, try to [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) the code yourself first. What does the `df['month']` column look like, for example? What is the data type of the column? When `df = df[df['month']==month]` happens, what is the value of `month`? What is its type? Does all that make sense? Similarly for the day column. Also make sure that `df` gets properly read in the first place. Does the corresponding file look like it ought to when you check it in a text editor or spreadsheet program?

Answer (score -1):

consider removing `day_of_week` and replace with `day_name`
from

`df = df[df['day_of_week'] == day.title()]`

Pandas understands `day_name`